# Angular2 & Firebase - How to store email and password to use 'reauathenticateWithCredential'

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

**What I'm trying to achieve**

- A simple update email and password 'form'.

**Issue**

- When I've recently signed in, changing the email works fine
- When I haven't recently authenticated, an error is thrown

**Questions**

- How do I use the 'reauathenticateWithCredential' method?
- Where would I store the users password to pass into the method?

**Change Email Form**

```js
saveNewEmailAddress(email: string) {
  this.authService.updateEmailAddress(email);
}
```

**Auth Service**

The email seems to appear in intelliSense (so i'm hoping that works :) ). However, how do I pass a password through?

```js
updateEmailAddress(email: string) {
    const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    const credentials = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(currentUser.email, password);
    currentUser.reauthenticateWithCredential(credentials).then(function () {
      currentUser.updateEmail(email).then(function () {
        // Success
      }).catch(function (error) {
        // An error happened.
      });
    })
  }
```

Any help here, code examples, advice would be greatly appreciated. Very new to this.

---

---

---

**UPDATE**

This is how i've got it to work. Please advise if this is good or not. What I've changed is:

- When attempting to change the email, I list the current email, a new email input field and a password field
- The password field is for the current password
- Once a new email address AND password have been entered, the 'save' button becomes enabled
- I take the new email and password and pass them to the auth service where I run the method to update the email

**Account Component HTML**

```html
      <!-- Password -->
      <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error': (customerForm.get('password').touched || customerForm.get('password').dirty) && !customerForm.get('password').valid }">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="passwordId">Password</label>
        <input #currentPassword class="form-control" id="passwordId" type="text" placeholder="Password(required)" formControlName="password"/>
          <span class="help-block" *ngIf="(customerForm.get('password').touched || customerForm.get('password').dirty) && customerForm.get('password').errors">
            <span *ngIf="customerForm.get('password').errors.required">
                Please enter your Password.
            </span>
          <span *ngIf="customerForm.get('password').errors.minlength"> The password must be longer than 10 characters. </span>
        </span>
      </div>

  <!-- Save Button -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" [disabled]="!customerForm.valid" (click)="saveNewEmailAddress(newEmail.value, currentPassword.value);"> Save </button>
  </div>
```

**Account Component TS**

```js
  saveNewEmailAddress(email: string, password: string) {
    this.authService.updateEmailAddress(email, password);
  }
```

**Auth Service**

```js
updateEmailAddress(email: string, password: string) {
    const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    const credentials = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(currentUser.email, password);
    currentUser.reauthenticateWithCredential(credentials).then(function () {
      currentUser.updateEmail(email).then(function () {
        console.log('i think it worked!');
        currentUser.sendEmailVerification().then(function () {
          console.log('email sent');
        }).catch(function (error) {
          // An error happened.
        });
      }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work this out by including a password confirmation in the email change pop up. That way I can carry the password value through into the service, therefore the reauthentication :)

Comment: Never store passwords on the client or pass them in URLs. This is extremely bad and undermines all security best practices and puts your users at risk. When reauthentication is required, you are supposed to ask the user to provide the password again. If you don't like that, use some other form of authentication such as OAuth.

Comment: Thanks @bojeil. I have made an update to my code above outlining the approach I'm taking. As I mentioned in my original post, I'm exceptionally new to this, so if you're able to say whether my approach works or provide code on how to do it safely that would be greatly appreciated. The documentation states to re-authenticate you need to pass in the users email and password. This is the only way I've found to include the password in that method.

Comment: Original docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user /

Comment: Stackoverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39909964/how-to-change-email-in-firebase-auth - It looks like the password is being passed through here too. Am I missing something? Or was my original answer (without code) misleading?

Comment: I may have misunderstood your original suggested solution. You have to create a credential with the password to reauthenticate but as long as you ask for it from the user and don't store it on the device, you are good to go.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for responding again. I ask the user for the password and pass that into the auth service to reauthenticate. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion on my end.